# What am I doing wrong to call this API?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

```
struct ID: Codable{
    var id: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case id = " "
    }
}

struct AnimalKeys: Codable{
    var names: String?
    var taxonomy: Taxonomy
    var locations: String?
    var characteristics: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case names = "name"
        case taxonomy = "taxonomy"
        case locations = "locations"
        case characteristics = "characteristics"
    }
}

struct Taxonomy: Codable{
    var kingdom: String?
    var phylum: String?
    var class1: String?
    var family: String?
    var scientificname: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case kingdom = "kingdom"
        case phylum = "phylum"
        case class1 = "class"
        case family = "family"
        case scientificname = "scientific_name"
    }
}


class AnimalModel {
    
    static let share = AnimalModel()
    
 var id: [ID] = []
    
    var animal: [AnimalKeys] = []
    
    var taxonomy: [Taxonomy] = []
    
    
    
    init(name: String){
        getAnimalApi(names: name)
    }
    
    private init(){
        
    }
    
    func getAnimalApi(names: String) {
        
        let headers = [
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "api-key",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "animals-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com"
        ]
        
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://animals-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/animals?name=\(names)")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse)
                print("good")
                var result: AnimalKeys?
                request.httpBody = data
                guard let data = data else{return}

                do {
                    result = try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimalKeys.self, from: data)
                    print(result?.names)

                } catch {
                    print("The file could not be loaded")
                }
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

This is my code and it states that the file could be loaded

Comment: Instead of meaningless `"The file could not be loaded"` print the `error`. And stop using `(NS)Mutable...` classes in Swift if there are native counterparts.

Comment: I assume the last sentence is missing the word “not”. When you catch an error then print that error instead of a hard coded string which is not very meaningful. So add `print(error)` to your `catch` clause. Then add the message and a sample of the json you are trying to decode to the question.

Comment: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
 is the result from print(error)

Comment: `request.httpBody = data`? Inside the closure? What? Print the response, it doesn't seem to match your Codable struct. Maybe `decode([AnimalKeys].self`?

Comment: Unrelated but `if (error != nil) {` and printing the optional error is pretty *objective-c-ish*. In Swift 5.7 just write `if let error {` or in earlier versions `if let error = error {` (no parentheses).

Comment: It keeps asking for a dictionary to store the key values. The link for the API is https://rapidapi.com/apininjas/api/animals-by-api-ninjas. Don't know why it's asking for this

Comment: You have the answer above in the comment by @larme, change `decode(AnimalKeys.self,` to `decode([AnimalKeys].self,`